# How can I test if a character is a vowel using a single if statement?

Tags: java

How can I test if a single character is a vowel, using a single `if` statement?

More practically, how can I consolidate my current logic below into a single `if` statement?

```
if (valor == 'a'); System.out.println("xdd");
if (valor == 'e'); System.out.println("xdd");
if (valor == 'i'); System.out.println("xdd");
if (valor == 'o'); System.out.println("xdd");
if (valor == 'u'); System.out.println("xdd");
```

Comment: Whats wrong with a switch case? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: That semicolon after if` is misplaced. This won’t work.

Comment: Duplicate of [can you have two conditions in an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44830259/can-you-have-two-conditions-in-an-if-statement)

Comment: You can use a [switch case](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), or [conditional operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

Comment: Generally speaking, 'aeiou' are not the only vowels in the world. Is this US-only code?

Comment: @user14387228 Yeah, but he only wants to know how to test characters with a single if statement. How he uses his new found powers is up to him. Will it be for good, or for awesome? All I know is we are all in his origin story now!

Answer (score 3):

Try this. This will work whether `valor` is a character or a string.

```
if ("aeiou".indexOf(valor) >= 0) {
    System.out.println("xdd");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try [String.indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int))

```
final String vowels = "aeiou";
char valor = 'e';
if (vowels.indexOf(valor) != -1) {
    System.out.println("xdd");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the `||` operator which basically serves as a `or` in a statement like so:

```
if(valor=='a'||valor=='e'||valor=='i'||valor=='o'||valor=='u'){
    System.out.println("xdd");
}
```

Since in this case, it will always print the same thing.

Comment: This is what i was looking for, ty men,rest of answers are great but not as simple as this one

Comment: @Legoruu If my answer answers your question, please consider accepting so future visitors can be assisted

Answer (score 1):

One easy method, which can also be easily expanded, is using an index string and checking if your variable is part of that String.

```
String vowels = "aeiou";
if (vowels.indexOf(valor) >= 0) {
    // do whatever you have to
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let `valor` is a character converted to String, then:

```
if ("AaEeIiOoUu".contains(valor)) {
    System.out.println("xdd");
}
```

Comment: `String#contains` requires a `CharSequence` argument, not a single `char`. And called with a `CharSequence` it would also yield `true` for e.g. `"ioO"`, which it shouldn’t.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The OP said *How can I test if a single character is a vowel,* So based on the OP's statement, it would be a `CharSequence` of one character.  So `ioO` is not relevant.

Comment: @WJS In OP’s code the type of `valor` is `char`. If it *isn’t* char, the test should naturally ensure that it’s only a single character long, this can’t just be assumed as given.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex.

String str = "a";

```
if (str.matches("[AaeEiIoOuU]") {
    System.out.println("It's a vowel!");
}
 else {
   System.out.println("it's not a vowel!");
}
```

Comment: Ah, totally right. I thought the only restriction fo `matches` is that it matches at the beginning but it also has to match the *entire* string. The behaviour of Python’s `re.match` is confusingly different, that’s why I misremembered.

Answer (score 0):

As many suggested, you can use `indexOf` or `||`. I'll not repeat myself. You can use something as follows as well,

```
public class VowelOrNot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String valor = "z";

        switch (valor.toLowerCase()) {
            case "a":
            case "e":
            case "i":
            case "o":
            case "u":
                System.out.println(valor + " is vowel");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(valor + " is consonant");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using switch case. Which is handy when you want to avoid if-else/if-if ladder in multiple scenarios. Basically, if the input is matched with any of the case then it prints that string is a vowel else it is a consonant. Note, that `break` is important. Otherwise it will check default case and print consonant if given `valor` is a vowel.

If you want, you replace `String` with `char` in the variable declaration and handle it appropriately in switch cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by using the if conditional statements with java logical OR operator.

**Using short circuit OR operator**

This will be more efficient because this will return true at the first point when java meets the satisfying  condition while checking the logical condition.

```
if(valor=='a'||valor=='e'||valor=='i'||valor=='o'||valor=='u'){
    System.out.println("xdd"); 
}
```